# SQL BOM Tree Joining

Tags: sql, sql-server

| SKU | BOM SKU | CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RM123 |  | D |
| WPR123 | RM123 | C |
| WPR456 | RM123 | C |
| 123 | WPR123 | B |
| 456 | WPR456 | A |

Imagine that all of this is in a single table as pictured. What I want is to retrieve the class of SKU 123 and 456 starting with the raw RM123. This seems like a looping join that I just can't get my head around. Help please.

Comment: As a human, how in the world you get there from RM123 at all?

Comment: Why make us imagine from a picture when you can [create a table for us and populate it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6993985091e7c185547a8921bee40cfa)? What is the desired output? Is the CLASS column relevant to the problem at all? Just telling us you want "a looping join" doesn't give us a start at helping solve the problem. It's like telling the doctor over the phone that I want to feel better.

Comment: Looks like you want a recursive CTE. Add the desired output to the question for better answers.

Comment: Table has been edited. RM123 makes WPR123 and WPR456. WPR123 and WPR456 make FG 123 and 456. 123 and 456 make nothing. They are the finished goods. What I need is a query that says this is the max class of RM123. The answer to this example would be A. I just dont know how to write a query or function that would continually join on SKU until theres nothing left to join on. Thanks doctor.

Comment: Thanks, @Serg. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *sounds* like you want a recursive CTE ([some background here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-ctes)).

With this table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ImagineThis
(
  SKU   varchar(32),
  BOM   varchar(32), 
  CLASS varchar(32)
);

INSERT dbo.ImagineThis(SKU,BOM,CLASS) VALUES
('RM123' , '',       'D'),
('WPR123', 'RM123' , 'C'),
('WPR456', 'RM123' , 'C'),
('123'   , 'WPR123', 'B'),
('456'   , 'WPR456', 'A');
```

One approach is:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT lvl = 1, SKU, BOM, CLASS, Path = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SKU)
  FROM dbo.ImagineThis
  WHERE BOM = ''
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT lvl = lvl + 1, i.SKU, i.BOM, i.CLASS, Path = cte.Path + '\' + i.SKU
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN dbo.ImagineThis AS i
  ON i.BOM = cte.SKU
)
SELECT * FROM cte OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32000);
```

Results:

| lvl | SKU | BOM | CLASS | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RM123 |  | D | RM123 |
| 2 | WPR123 | RM123 | C | RM123\WPR123 |
| 2 | WPR456 | RM123 | C | RM123\WPR456 |
| 3 | 456 | WPR456 | A | RM123\WPR456\456 |
| 3 | 123 | WPR123 | B | RM123\WPR123\123 |

Though I'm not sure how you came to the answer "A" since these two paths seem "equal" and both A and B are at the same "level." You can see this by limiting the output to the highest level:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  ...
)
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
  FROM cte 
  ORDER BY lvl DESC
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32000);
```

Why do you consider "A" as the final product?

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1a509341e3dd6b9c11f645ac7dc7bbd)

### As for why A

> "A" (class) would be the final answer in terms of heirachary. A = 1, B = 2, etc,. I'd create either a temp table or CTE with this definition.

Ok:

```
DECLARE @ClassHierarchy table(Class varchar(32), Ordering tinyint);
INSERT @ClassHierarchy VALUES('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('B',4);

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT lvl = 1, SKU, BOM, CLASS, Path = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SKU)
  FROM dbo.ImagineThis
  WHERE BOM = ''
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT lvl = lvl + 1, i.SKU, i.BOM, i.CLASS, Path = cte.Path + '\' + i.SKU
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN dbo.ImagineThis AS i
  ON i.BOM = cte.SKU
)
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES cte.*
  FROM cte 
  INNER JOIN @ClassHierarchy AS h
  ON cte.CLASS = h.Class
  ORDER BY lvl DESC, h.Ordering
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32000);
```

Results:

| lvl | SKU | BOM | CLASS | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 456 | WPR456 | A | RM123\WPR456\456 |

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f949aced4b48534b1914566c10dbedf)

Comment: Thank Aaron. I'm working through your solution now. "A" (class) would be the final answer in terms of heirachary. A = 1, B = 2, etc,. I'd create either a temp table or CTE with this definition. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @RyanHass You should update the question with those details (both that desired result is A and _exactly_ why).